# Django ForeignKey in ManytoMany field is displayed as None

Tags: django, database, sqlite, python-3.x

I got a model that uses a foreignkey in a manytomany field:

```
class DefinitionTag(models.Model):
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="Tag")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tag


class Definition(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    definition = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    fundstellen = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    wissenswertes = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(DefinitionTag)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

this works, and in the admin everything is set up so i can use it. The problem is if i try to display a table with the database entries in my view with the code:

```
def home(request):
    query_results = Definition.objects.all()

    context = {
        "query_results": query_results
    }
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

and in html:

```
{% for item in query_results %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.definition }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.fundstellen }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.wissenswertes }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.tags }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

In the tag column it gives me only:

DefinitionTag.None

How can i display there all the tags choosen in the manytomany field?

I hope i'll get a hint!
Thanks

Comment: Take a look at [that answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411961/querying-many-to-many-fields-in-django-template). you need to iterate through `item.tags.all`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to loop on the m2m field to get all tags. Just referring to it won't give you individual tags that link to it:

```
{% for item in query_results %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.definition }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.fundstellen }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.wissenswertes }}</td>
        <td>
            {% for tag in item.tags.all %}
                {{ tag }}
            {% endfor %}
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

If you are not sure how to get all items from m2m field, check out [django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/).

Answer (score 3):

Try looping through the tag:

```
{% for tag in item.tags.all %}
    {{ tag }}
{% endfor %}
```