# Show manytomany field in Django list view

Tags: django

I am trying to show the values of a manytomany field called teachers in a Django ListView.

At present my model looks like this:

```
class Classform(models.Model):

    # Fields
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = extension_fields.AutoSlugField(populate_from='name', blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False)

    # Relationship Fields
    school = models.ForeignKey('eduly.School', default=1)
    teachers = models.ManyToManyField('eduly.Teacher', )
```

My ListView looks like this:

```
class ClassformListView(GroupRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Classform
    group_required = [u"school_admin"]
    login_url = "/login/"
    raise_exception = True
```

And my template for the list view looks like this:

```
<tr>
<td>{{object.pk}}</td>
<td><a href="{{object.get_absolute_url}}">{{object}}</a></td>
<td>{{ object.name }}</td>
<td>{{ object.teachers }}</td>
<td>{{ object.created }}</td>
<td>{{ object.last_updated }}</td>
</tr>
```

When this code runs the displayed value for `object.teachers` is `appname.Teacher.None`

I have noticed that Django has created a table called `appname_classform` and also a table called 'appname_classform_teachers' (presumably for the manytomany field) but I am not sure how I need to change `object.teachers` to get the name of the teachers. The 'appname_classform_teachers' contains valid entries for teachers in the app name_teachers table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Querying Many to many fields in django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411961/querying-many-to-many-fields-in-django-template)

Comment: Thanks @ClémentDenoix that has the answer I need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `object.teachers.all` instead to get the actual queryset.

-- EDIT --
To render these in a custom way:

```
{% for objs_teacher in object.teachers.all %}
    <p>{{ objs_teacher.first_name }}</p>
    <p>{{ objs_teacher.last_name }}</p>
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

You can access the indevidual fields in the loop to make it look how you want.

Comment: That gets me way closer, I now get the teacher names but I get other text too. This is what I see now: <QuerySet [<Teacher: Samual Mayweather>]>

Comment: That's because you were printing out the queryset object. See my answers edit.